# Executor wait for ever in a singleton class

Tags: java, singleton, executorservice

I have implemented a singleton (manager) to manage some related tasks, inside this manager I am using an executor to handle 10 task at the same time, I was using linkedBlockingQueue with no limit, and that's working good so far, but now I need to set a limitation to my executor queue because I have a lot of tasks (hundreds of thousands tasks), and I don’t want to put them all in my queue that causing me a performance issues, so what I have done:

here is my Executor :

```
public class MyThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

public MyThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
    super(corePoolSize, corePoolSize + 5, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, workQueue);
}


@Override
protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
    super.beforeExecute(t, r);
    //Do something to my task
}

@Override
protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
    super.afterExecute(r, t);
    if(t != null) {
        // 
    } else {
        //Do something to my task
    }
}
}
```

and here is my manager :

```
public final class MyManager {

private static MyManager manager = new MyManager();
public static final int queueMaxSize = 100;
private BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(queueMaxSize);
private ExecutorService executor = new MyThreadPoolExecutor(10, workQueue);


/**
 * constructor
 */
private MyManager() {}

public static MyManager getInstance(){

    if (manager == null){
        synchronized(MyManager.class){
            if (manager == null){
                manager = new MyManager();
            }
        }
    }
    return manager;
}

/**
 */
public void executeTask(Integer key){
    executeTask(key, Locale.getDefault());
}

/**
 */
public void executeTask(Integer key, Locale locale) {
    Tasker task = new Tasker(key, locale);
    executor.execute(task);
}
}
```

and here the class that asking to do the tasks :

```
public class MyClass {

public void doTasks() {
    //geting my tasks in array of list, its holding more than 900 000 tasks,
    //sometimes its holding up to 10 million task like :
    MyManager.getInstance().isFull() {\\wait, then ask again}

    ArrayList<Integer> myTasks = getAllTasksIds();

    for(Integer id : myTasks) {
        //if i perform a waiting here it will be waiting for ever.
        MyManaget.getInstance().executeTask(id);
    }
}

}
```

What I want exactly to wait the executor until finish his queue tasks, then re-full it again.

But the problem is when I try to wait based on queue size, the executor won’t work, and its wait forever because the queue still full.

Comment: Why bother with the lazy initialization and double locking shennanigans when setting up your Manager? You've already initialized it by the looks of things.

Comment: Your `getInstance` method should just be: `public static MyManager getInstance() { return manager; }`.

Comment: You could subclass ArrayBlockingQueue that knows it's maxsize and has a callback method (or object that knows from where to fill) that fills it back when it becomes empty.

Comment: @DaveHowes and assylias, its our code standers, i have nothing to do with that, anyway thanks guys.

Comment: @Tala, Yea i know that, i already know when my queue get full, the problem is in my manager if i want to access to ask about my queue status, then my executor won't work because the synchronized manager.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you just use a bounded blocking queue (i.e. specify a bound of a BlockingQueue)? If you use a bounded blocking queue (of which size you can choose yourself), your producer will block when the queue is full, and will resume publishing tasks when a task is consumed from a queue. This way, you can avoid putting too much stuff too quickly onto the queue, but also avoid putting too less on the queue. That's kind of the point of blocking queues...

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code but instead of using ArrayBlockingQueue I extended it with this... And it works. Try it:

```
public static class MyBlockingQueue extends ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID= -9016421283603545618L;

    public static Lock lock= new ReentrantLock();
    public static Condition condition= lock.newCondition();
    public static volatile Boolean isWaiting= false;

    public MyBlockingQueue(int capacity) {
        super(capacity, true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offer(Runnable e) {
        if (remainingCapacity() == 0) {
            try {
                isWaiting= true;
                condition.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return super.offer(e);
    }

    @Override
    public Runnable take() throws InterruptedException {
        Runnable take= super.take();
        if (remainingCapacity() > 0 && isWaiting) {
            isWaiting= false;
            condition.signal();
        }
        return take;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yea i have tried this one, the problem is in my manager i think, if i want to access to ask about my queue status, then my executor won't work because the synchronized manager. see the update MyClass.